# Объединить объекты в массиве по заданному признаку

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется массив из объектов. как можно объединить несколько из них, если у них есть один общий признак (одинаковое свойство)?
К примеру есть массив:

```
[
  {
      "Text": "Прочие дебиторы",
      "Value": "237528"
  },
  {
      "Text": "=",
      "Operation": true
  },
  {
      "Text": "(",
      "Operation": true
  }
];
```

У двух элементов массива есть одно общее свойство `Operaion: true`.
на выходе нужно получить:

```
[
  {
      "Text": "Прочие дебиторы",
      "Value": "237528"
  },
  {
      "Text": "=(",
      "Operation": true
  }
]
```

Comment: у них у всех есть общее свойство `text`. По каким свойствам надо сравнивать? и собственно, вы сами то пробовали решить задачу, что не получилось?

Comment: Operaion: true - свойство по которым надо сравнивать.
Пробовал. какой-то костыль получается с кучами циклами и условиями...может кто поопытнее знает как...

Comment: То есть надо взять и объединить (сложить свойство `text`) элементы у которых имеется свойство `operation` со значением `true`, а все другие элементы не трогать?

Comment: Общее поля может быть любое или это всего Operation ? Там всегда булевское значение или тоже могут быть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr  = [
  {'Text': 'Прочие дебиторы', 'Value': '237528'},
  {'Text': '=', 'Operation': true},
  {'Text': '(','Operation': true}
];

var data = arr.filter(t => t['Operation'] !== true);

data.push(
  {
    'Text': arr.map(e => e['Operation'] === true ? e['Text'] : '').join(''),
    'Operation': true
  }
);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: мне кажется там все таки более общее решение требуется. Типа набора перечня свойства, и сгруппировать надо по произвольным значениям

Comment: Код, к слову, можно было бы сократить: ```console.log(arr.filter(x => !x.Operation).concat({'Text':arr.map(x => x.Operation ? x.Text : '').join(''),'Operation':true}));```

Comment: @teran, можете привести примеры? до и после?

Comment: @gregzakharov, ну-с, да, но у нас тут не конкурс кода-гольфа :)